# How to use a button from my other class in a CountDownTimer | Beginner

Tags: java, class, button

I'm creating a Reaction time Test app, with one button. I create this button in my first Class: ReactionTestActivity. Now I want to use it in my CountDownTimer, but how do I do this?

```
public class CDT extends CountDownTimer {

    public CDT (long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, ReactionTestActivity RAT){
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }


    public void onFinish(){
        button.setText("press");
    }



    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of run-time environment? Swing? Android?

Comment: I think CountDownTimer is Android only.

Answer (score 0):

You just created the class.  Assuming you're doing Android, you need to do the rest of Android stuff:

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
    private Button startB;
    public TextView text;
    private final long startTime = 30 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        startB.setOnClickListener(this);
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);

        //NOTE:  I don't know what you expect as the third parameter
        countDownTimer = new CDT(startTime, interval, null);

        text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!timerHasStarted) {
             countDownTimer.start();
             timerHasStarted = true;
             startB.setText("STOP");
         } else {
             countDownTimer.cancel();
             timerHasStarted = false;
             startB.setText("RESTART");
         }
    }


    public class CDT extends CountDownTimer {
        //your class definition that you wrote above.
    }

}
```

Now you need the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bgi" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/timer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:textSize="50dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Source:

http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html